# Installing Groovy and Gradle plugins in Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09) offline

Tags: eclipse, groovy, offline, php-ziparchive

I am trying to add the latest groovy IDE plugin to Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09). The network security blocks access to eclipse marketplace and other sites like dist.springsource.org. Where can I download the appropriate zip archive for offline installation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each of the release notes pages on the groovy/groovy-eclipse github site have update site archive links at the bottom.